# background color does not change with ng-class condition in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ng-class, angularjs-material

All other css element working fine rather background-color and color.

```
    <md-button class="md-raised" ng-style="style1"
                       ng-click="style1=style; style2=null;style3=null;style4=null;removable=0;loadPorcessBarcodes();Head.ProcessMode=1" 
                       ng-class="{'selected-btn': Head.ProcessMode == 1}">Auto Nozzle From Stock</md-button>
```

**My css:**

```
.selected-btn {
        padding: 2px;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: #ffffff;
        background-color: #122b01;
    }
```

Comment: are `background-color` and `color` properties are also mentioned in inline styles?

Comment: yes, it's working ng-click and i also change the change the class when data already selected from server. So there has no manual click to keep it focus. @PankajParkar

Comment: See if such properties already mentioned in `style1` prop, so inline style takes 1st preference, try overriding those properties from `class` wouldn't work(unless they are marked as !important)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as you've been using `ng-style`, which is already applying `background-color` and `color` style. So even though you apply a class over it with the overridden property, the same element would not reflect, because inline CSS takes first preference. If you wanted to enforce `background-color` and `color` properties to be enforced then mark them as `!important` to see the expected behavior.

---

Other better way to solve this problem would moving `style1` to new class and apply it using `ng-class` with its appropriate expression.